# How to use two different items in a query

Tags: prometheus, grafana, dashboard

I have started working with Prometheus / Grafana. I have some data from my Kubernetes cluster that I want to dashboard. Specifically for the persistent volume claims, I want to show the current free space in a table or some such.

This metric on its own does not exist. However, I can get the total capacity using this query: `px_volume_fs_capacity_bytes{}`

This returns a list of values that has this structure:

```
px_volume_fs_capacity_bytes{app_kubernetes_io_instance="redis",app_kubernetes_io_name="redis",cluster="px-cluster-6b616c47-4d56-414c-9638-c95dcde99d4c",clusterUUID="52eff814-17e0-485e-b312-4be39d4e386f",endpoint="px-api",exported_namespace="database",instance="192.168.2.9:9001",job="portworx-service",namespace="portworx",node="kubenode02",nodeID="dfd4576e-185c-48c3-9542-8724319de0ac",pod="px-cluster-6b616c47-4d56-414c-9638-c95dcde99d4c-m988d",priority_io="high",pvc="redis-data-redis-master-0",repl="1",service="portworx-service",volumeid="777692050373571690",volumename="pvc-6de4deb8-19ac-4340-be43-2769b733dc89",app_kubernetes_io_component="master"}
```

There is one of these entries for each persistent volume. I can also do the same for bytes used. What I want to be able to do is something like:

```
for each $persistent_volume_name (px_volume_fs_used_bytes/px_volume_fs_capacity_bytes)
```

Note that the lable value pvc exists in both data sets so i hoped to use that as a lookup between them.

Where I would then get a table like this:

| Volume Lable | Free Space (MB) |
| --- | --- |
| persistent_vol_label01 | 500MB |
| persistent_vol_label02 | 100MB |
| persistent_vol_label03 | 200MB |

I could of course make a single box for each of these items but I was hoping to make one dynamic view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus is automatically doing "foreach".

So if you guarantee that in both metrics label `volumename` is unique, and present in both metrics at the same time, you can simply use query

```
px_volume_fs_used_bytes
/ on(volumename)
px_volume_fs_capacity_bytes
```

It will take all `px_volume_fs_used_bytes` match appropriate `px_volume_fs_capacity_bytes` (with the same value of label `volumename`) and return result of division.

Comment: This was the answer. Knowing that I could do on(someColumnName) was the critical bit that none of the tutorials or other simple instructions I had read included. Don't suppose someone has like a cheat sheet for this somewhere?

Comment: @EdwardS., not much to include into cheatsheet. But it's mentioned in categories like "series matching" in general promql cheatsheets, as i can see after quick googling. Or [here](https://promlabs.com/promql-cheat-sheet/) it's called math between series.